# Convert an Arraylist of Textviews into 2d String array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an arraylist of 55 textview elements and I want to convert it into an 2d array of Strings 5 columns x 11 rows, where I want to save their text.

I do the following but I get a repeated 11 set of same values

```
            String[][] mazeArray = new String[5][11];

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

                for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
                {
                    mazeArray[i][j] = finalTotalList.get(j).getText().toString();
                }
            }
```

what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know for sure what you are doing wrong without the error, but here is what I would suspect is causing you problems. Right now, you get the text from the first 11 text views (indices 0-10)  5 times repeatedly.

```
String[][] mazeArray = new String[5][11];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
       {
           //edited to account for index still increasing when moving to a new row
           mazeArray[i][j] = finalTotalList.get(11*i+j).getText().toString();
       }
    }
```